# Google Javascript v8 - multithreading

Tags: javascript, multithreading, v8

Suppose I have the following piece of code

```
bool run (void)
{
    HandleScope hande_scope;
    Handle<String> source;
    Local<Script> script;
    Persistent<Context> context;

    context = Context::New();
    Context::Scope context_scope(context);

    script = Script::Compile("var a = 1; var b = 2;");
    Local<Value> result = script->Run();

    if (result.IsEmpty())
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}
```

Is it true that one cannot execute this code using multiple threads? It seems like `HandleScope` is not designed to be used in multithreaded applications.
I can use the `v8::Locker` and `v8::Unlocker` methodes but that would always give me execution traces as this:

```
t1: a = 1
t1: b = 2

t2: a = 1
t2: b = 2
```

I hope someone can give me a hint on getting this code multithreaded so that a possible execution trace could like this:

```
t1: a = 1
t2: a = 1

t1: b = 2
t2: b = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [v8 issue 510](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=510), a feature called "Isolates" was added to the trunk some months back.  This should allow multiple (non-interacting) instances of v8 in a single process.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/v8-users/browse_thread/thread/3f66bb4cf86d836e/163379d7082c317d?#163379d7082c317d). The v8 engine has a Locker class, that lets you preempt your code. With this you can use multiple threads.